# The /remote-desktop tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [remote-desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) be about the Windows [Remote Desktop Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) and associated tools, or about remote GUI in general, or about desktop sharing?

The current usage seems like a blend of all three.

What should [remote-desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) be about, and what should questions that turn out to be incorrectly tagged be retagged to?

Answer (score 2):

We could use [rdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdp) for Remote Desktop Protocol, but when I hear people say "remote desktop" they're almost always talking about that, so we should probably leave it as that. Normally people say VNC or X when they're talking about remote Linux GUIs, so we could probably go with [vnc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vnc) and [remote-x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-x)/[remote-x11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-x11) for those